# If a character can make multiple attacks as part of an Attack action, do all of them need to be done with a light weapon to use Two-Weapon Fighting?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack, two-weapon-fighting, multiattack

The [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) rule states:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand.

If the character can make multiple attacks as part of the Attack action, do all of them need to be done with a light melee weapon to qualify for making the bonus-action attack?

Specifically, can I make one attack with a light melee weapon in one hand and make one bite attack with a natural weapon, and then use my bonus action to make an attack with a second light melee weapon in the other hand?

Comment: Related: "[Can I Two-Weapon fight after Two-Handed-Weapon fighting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140515)"

Comment: Note that since TWF requires you to be holding a light weapon in each hand, this situation would be very unlikely to arise in practice. You'd have to do something like attacking while holding 2 light weapons to trigger TWF, then drop one of them on the ground and draw a non-light weapon and attack with that.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Or you use a natural bite weapon as described in the question. In my case I have it from being a Path of the Beast Barbarian.

Comment: @Akix That question, or at least its second answer, does not answer this question. The fact that in this case the light weapons are in hand at the start of the Attack action and throughout the entire Attack action as well means that under multiple possible interpretations of what triggers TWF this would *still* work. The other question fails both of these potential requirements

Comment: @Medix2 you are right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### No, only one attack needs to be with a light melee weapon.

The sufficient condition for using TWF is:

> you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand

If you attack with your shortsword in your left hand, biting something does not change the fact that you have attacked with a light melee weapon you are holding in one hand.