# Does the attack with a light melee weapon required for Two-Weapon Fighting have to be part of TWF's required Attack Action?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, two-weapon-fighting

Two-Weapon Fighting states:

> "When *you take the attack action* ***and*** *attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand*, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand." **Emphasis mine**

It never actually says that the attack with the light melee weapon has to be part of the attack action, just that you must "take the attack action" **and** "attack with a light melee weapon..."

There have already been some questions regarding when you have to actually be wielding the light weapons required for Two-Weapon Fighting. [Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140515), [Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73050), and [Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120599).

And to satisfies any of those, say the following scenario occurs:

It is Alice's turn, and she starts her turn wielding two light melee weapons, say, two daggers.

She makes an opportunity attack against a creature using one of these weapons (this is possible, for example, if a creature had used the ready action to move).

She drops one of her daggers (a free action), then takes the attack action and as part of the attack she draws a non-light weapon, say, a quarterstaff, and finally she attacks using this quarterstaff.

And so now I wonder, is there any reason, RAW, that she would not be able to use her bonus action to attack with the other dagger which she is still holding because she has technically fulfilled both requirements of Two-Weapon Fighting: "taking the attack action" **and** "attacking with a light melee weapon..."?

Comment: Related: [Does Two-Weapon fighting work if you aren't holding both weapons when you take the Attack action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120599)

Comment: @Medix2 No need to remove it, if we tag it as a duplicate that'll help search engine optimization. Duplicate questions are good for the site, so long as they're made in good faith and aren't literal, word-for-word replications of the question they've been tagged as.

Comment: I'm still unclear here. Are you asking if you can engage TWF in a scenario when you start your attack you don't have it drawn? Or are you asking if you can use you can draw a different weapon as part of your attack action then with what you're using to attack?

Comment: As you've indicated this is a dupe, I'd like to point out that your capitalisation in your quote is incorrect and that could be part of why you are confused about Attack vs attack here. I'm assuming you may have used Roll20 for your source which improperly capitalizes many things. The Q&A this is duped to has the correct caps.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose, Oh I did use Roll20, but no I was not confused by their capitalization usage, thank you though

Comment: OKeydoke. As long as that dupe was the dupe and you're all set :)